# Prevent customtkinter/tkinter from clicking trough transparent widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm working on a GUI using customtkinter, and some elements have transparency. For those elements, I use `wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", TransparentColor)` and give the `TransparentColor` color to the widgets. However, when I click on those elements or widgets, the app doesn't capture the click, and instead, the program that is behind the app receives it. I also use the `BlurWindow` module so the transparent widgets and elements have the blurred background.